# Highcharts candlestick chart data over written by that of other

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

I have two candlestick graphs displaying on the same page. They occupy the same space, but one is hidden while the other is displayed, like so:

`<div class="box" id="box1">
    <div class="box-body">
        <div id="chart1"></div>
    </div>
</div>`

`<div class="box" id="box2">
    <div class="box-body">
        <div id="chart2"></div>
    </div>
</div>`

I draw a chart in each of the chart divs above, and that works fine. I use buttons to select a range, and that is when the trouble starts. If I click any of the zoom buttons in either chart1 or chart2, the data series in chart1 appears to be written over by the data in chart2, meaning the series of chart2 now also appears in chart1 although with correct the zoom level already selected for chart1.

Do I need to name the charts in a specific way to separate the charts from the data series properly? This is my charting code:

```
 $(target).highcharts('StockChart', {
    title: { text: title },
    chart : {
        backgroundColor: "none",
        plotBackgroundColor: "none",
    },
    rangeSelector : {
    buttons : [
            { type : 'hour', count : 6, text : '6h' },
            { type : 'hour', count : 24, text : '24h' },
            { type : 'day', count : 2, text : '2d' },
            { type : 'day', count : 4, text : '4d' },
            { type : 'week', count : 1, text : '1w' },
            { type : 'week', count : 2, text : '2w' },
            { type : 'month', count : 1, text : '1m' },
            { type : 'all', count : 1, text : 'All' }
                ],
        selected : 6,
        inputEnabled : false
    },
    scrollbar: { enabled: false },
    credits: { enabled: false },
    exporting: { enabled: false },
    yAxis: {
        title: { text: yaxislabel },
    },
    series : [{
        type: 'candlestick',
        data : data,
        tooltip: {
            valueDecimals: 2
        },
    }]
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that Highcharts doesn't work on the copy of the data, but uses original object. So solution is to pass on copy of the data, for example:

```
data : $.extend(true, [], data),
```

Comment: I did provide a different data source for the two plots, so I was not expecting this to work, but it did! Thank you! I have no idea why though...

Comment: It looks like the same data source. Maybe somewhere else in your code you are using the same variable or something similar. Hard to say without full code review.